# Mouse Events Unknown Error which I cannot rectify

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouse-listeners

I am learning java and while doing a MouseListener problem I am facing an error in the class declaration, tried everything known to me please help me out.
According to me I have done all the coding correctly, Pasted the code in IDE too but getting the same error.

Thanks

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import javax.swing.*;

       public class Sub extends JFrame      
    {
private JPanel mousepanel;
private JLabel statusbar;

public Sub()
{
    super("Mouse Events");
    // we didnt have a FlowLayout as we had in previous programs

    mousepanel = new JPanel();
    mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(mousepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //BorderLayout used instead of FlowLayout and it will place it in the center of the window.

    statusbar = new JLabel("Default");
    add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // same as above

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);
    mousepanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

            private class thehandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d, %d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("You press down the mouse.");
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("You released the mouse.");
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("You enetered the mouse panel area.");
            mousepanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("The mouse has left the window.");
            mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        //these aremouse motion events

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("Your are dragging the mouse.");
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
        {
            statusbar.setText("You moded the mouse.");
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the error that you're running into?

Comment: problem has been solved...by the solutions provided below...still thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your curly brackets and use some IDE it will help you to rectify errors more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `thehandler` class definition out of the scope of the `Sub` constructor.

*Sidenote:* Class names begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I have been disabled from posting more questions on this site so please up rate my question...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move your class definition outside of the constructor like this:

```
public Sub() {
    // ... rest of code
}

// ... rest of code

private class thehandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    // ... rest of code
}
```